# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} f_n$ has unbounded variation on every $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$ with $a < b$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation

Consider $n\in \Bbb N$, and define a piecewise linear function $f_n: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ so that the graph of $f_n$ contains the points $\{(k \cdot 2^{-n}, (-1)^k)\}_{0\le k\le 2^n}$. Define $f: =\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} f_n$. Since $|f_n| \le 1$ and $\sum_{n\ge 1} 2^{-n} < \infty$, $f$ is continuous. How would you show that $f$ has unbounded variation on every closed subinterval $[a,b]$ of $[0,1]$ with $a < b$?

The points $\{k \cdot 2^{-n}\}_{0\le k\le 2^n}$ form a partition of $[0,1]$ for every $n\ge 1$, so it seems a natural choice for a partition of $[a,b]$ to consider would consist of $\{a,b\}$ and points from $\{k \cdot 2^{-n}\}_{0\le k\le 2^n}$ that fall in the interval $[a,b]$.

---

P.S. This is what $f_2$ looks like:

[image]

The plots of $\{f_n\}$ will just have more "oscillations" as $n$ increases.

**Edit:** The current answer looks good. However, is there a way to avoid using differentiability a.e. of functions of bounded variation - perhaps directly computing the variation?

Comment: Just an idea to avoid using differentiability that I didn't push more : Try to show using the fractal structure of $f$ that the total variation of $f$ on some segment $[a,b]$ equals it total variation on $\left[a,\frac{a + b}{2}\right]$ and on$\left[\frac{a + b}{2},b\right]$. As it also equals their sum, they all must be $0$ or $+\infty$. You conclude by saying that $f$ is not constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, $f_n$ can be periodically extended to the whole $\mathbb R$, and then $f$ is a continuous function defined on $\mathbb R$ with period $1$. This extension is merely for  simplicity of the proof below. We claim that

> The function $f$ is not differentiable at any $x_0\in\mathbb R$.

From the above claim, we know that $f$ is of unbounded variation on any closed interval, since a continuous function of bounded variation is differentiable almost everywhere, see the last line of the introduction part of [this wikipieda page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#).

We prove the claim using the following lemma.

> **Lemma.**  Let $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $x_0\in\mathbb R$. Assume that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then for any non-decreasing sequence $\{u_n\}_{n\geq1}$ and any non-increasing sequence $\{v_n\}_{n\geq1}$ with $u_n\leq x_0\leq v_n$ satisying $v_n-u_n>0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(v_n-u_n)=0$, there holds
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(v_n)-f(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}=f'(x_0).$$

It is not hard to prove this lemma, so we left the proof to reader.

Now we show that $f$ defined in OP is not differentiable at any point. Let $x_0$ be any real number. We assume that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and we look for a contradiction. For each $n\in\mathbb N_{\geq1}$, there exists a unique $m_n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\frac{m_n}{2^n}\leq x_0< \frac{m_n+1}{2^n}$. We take $u_n=\frac{m_n}{2^n}, v_n=\frac{m_n+1}{2^n}$, then $u_n\leq x_0< v_n$, $\{u_n\}$ is non-decreasing, $\{v_n\}$ is non-increasing, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(v_n-u_n)=0$. By definition, $u_n$ and $v_n$ lie in the same segment of $f_n$, so they lie in the same segment of $f_k$ for all $k\leq n$. Hence, for $1\leq k\leq n$ we have $f_k(v_n)-f_k(u_n)=\pm 2^{k+1}(v_n-u_n)$. For $k\geq n+1$, we have $f_k(u_n)=(-1)^{2^{k-n}m_n}=1=(-1)^{2^{k-n}(m_n+1)}=f_k(v_n)$. Therefore,
$$\frac12\frac{f(v_n)-f(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}=\frac12 \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}\frac{f_k(v_n)-f_k(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}=\sum_{k=1}^n(\pm1).$$
As a result, if $n$ is odd, then $\frac12\frac{f(v_n)-f(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}$ is odd; if $n$ is even, then $\frac12\frac{f(v_n)-f(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}$ is even. Thus the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12\frac{f(v_n)-f(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}$$
does not exist. This contradicts to our assumption of the differentiability of $f$ at $x_0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks for your comments! I've editted my answer according to your concern. How's my proof now?

Comment: The proof is OK now. I fixed the small last issue.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thank you very very much!  :)

Comment: @Feng Is there a way to avoid using differentiability a.e. of functions of bounded variation - perhaps directly computing the variation?

Comment: @stoic-santiago Maybe. I tried but I failed.